# How can I access the sessionStorage key-value pairs of a domain other than current page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, session-storage

I would like to know how to programmatically change the javascript context of the console (image of the context menu attached).

I would like to do this to programmatically access session storage of a site while on a separate domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `sessionStorage` is by definition scoped to the current origin, and there is no cross-origin mechanism by which you can access the store for a different origin.